# Bitrix don't send access token oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, bitrix

I tried to connect with bitrix using software Postman API.
The goal was to test some REST comments, but I have problem with authorization. 
Using Postman I filled up: auth url, access token url, Client ID and Client secret of my bitrix, after that login page is visible and I entered login and password. In return a get html version of login page without access token. 
When I tried authorization using my application I have similar same situation, the response looks like:

```
div d="bx_incl_area_1" 
{"access_token":"token",
"expires_in":3600,
"scope":"application_permissions",
"domain":"my bitrix IP",
"server_endpoint":"https:\/\/oauth.bitrix.info\/rest\/",
"status":"L",
"client_endpoint":"http:\/\/My bitrix IP\/rest\/",
"member_id":"member id",
"user_id":"270",
"refresh_token":"refresh token"}
```

JSON looks good but this prefix `( div d="bx_incl_area_1")` makes mistake in aouth authorisation. Do you know any solution of this problem?